# React useReducer dispatch not re-rendering the component after using fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Here I am updating the state through react useReducer after deleting the task. I am sending `DELETE` request through `fetch API` and at the end of the callback function I am dispatching an action to update the state. But the state is not updated.

```
const deleteTask = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("delete task");
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/", {
      method: "DELETE",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ _id: state.task._id }),
    });
    dispatch({ type: "deleteTask", task: undefined });
  };
```

But when I change the code as follows:

```
const deleteTask = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "deleteTask", task: undefined });
    console.log("delete task");
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/", {
      method: "DELETE",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ _id: state.task._id }),
    });
  };
```

The re-render occurs i.e the state is updated. Can someone tell me why is this happening?

And this is my `delete` reducer function.

```
else if (action.type === "deleteTask") {
    return {
      ...state,
      isEditing: !state.isEditing,
      task: action.task,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your delete reducer function...!

Comment: @BhargavGarnara I have just updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This kind of same issue I also have faced.
- In first situation, dispatch is after await fetch api and make sure
  you have sent something res.send from backend because api call always
  wants some response to complete api call request.
- Until it will not get any response api call can't be completed so in
  function, it will stuck at code of line of await fetch api and not
  going to call dispatch action as api call is incompleted.
- **So Make sure res.send in delete route bakcend.**

And also try to do this...

```
let response = await fetch(//api call//)
console.log(response)
```

so that you will get to know what is getting as response.

I hope it will work it out. let me know if not...Thank You...!

Comment: problem is at frontend side, no request done to backend. And backend is java app. so sorry, but your answer is irrelevant here.